# Is it possible to use d8 to measure memory usage?

Tags: javascript, webos, v8

With the release of the Closure compiler, I was hoping to see if there was a difference in memory usage between a js file using the compiler and one which had not.

In particular, on a mobile platform like Palm's WebOS, the very limited amount of memory available means that every little bit will help.

EDIT: I should point out that d8 is the v8 javascript engine debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about d8 but since the [V8 debugger API](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol) doesn't have anything that can give you memory consumption so I'm guessing that the answer is **no**.

However the [V8 profiler](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/ProfilingChromiumWithV8) accepts flags to give information about the *heap usage*, which should be what you want. Check the project's wiki page for further instructions.